# How can I iterate through a vector to generate new objects?

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I've generated a vector from a relatively large CSV file and need to make objects out of each row. Problem is, there are 102 columns, so manually writing the object parameters is out of the question.

```
Data colNames;

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < content[i].size(); j++) {
        string column = "col" + j;
        colNames.column = content[i][j];

    }
}
```

Obviously, my syntax is wrong, but despite long google searches, I have yet to find anything that can really do this.

The object that is to be created is very simple: each column has its own value therein:

```
class Data
{
public:
    string col0;
    string col1;
    string col2;
    string col3;
    string col4;
    string col5;
    string col6;
    string col7;
    string col8;
    string col9;
    string col10;
    string col11;
    string col12;
    string col13;
    string col14;
         (...)
```

In other words, for j = 0, colNames.col0 needs to be updated, and so on.

Comment: When you have many sequentially named or numbered variables like this you probably want an array or library container. Make your problem go away.

Comment: What is surprising is that you are already using something that looks like an array in the original code you posted, but then for some reason, you didn't use an array in the `Data` class.

Comment: Variable names don't exist at run time. They may hang around for debugging information to help out us humans, but the computer only cares where the variable is in storage, so the name is replaced by an address or an offset from an address.

Comment: This is turning into an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  What high-level goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: BTW, the 'Y` part of the XY is this: *I've generated a vector from a relatively large CSV file and need to make objects out of each row.*  -- What do you mean by "make objects out of each row"?  Why not handle `content[i][j]` as-is, without having to "create an object"?  Assuming that `content` is a 2D vector, then `content[i]` contains the row data.  Why create a duplicate of this data?

Comment: It's the opening stages of a "Learn a language on your own" class - unfortunately, the instructions are very clear that each row of the csv must be stored as its own object. Why? No idea. I've never had to deal with such a large and arbitrary dataset before, so I'm definitely a bit uneasy

Comment: It is the "as its own object" that doesn't make sense or is not clear.  Maybe `class Data { std::vector<std::string> stringData; };` is what you are looking for?  And if so, simply copy `content[i]` to `stringData`?

Comment: Make the colNames thing a vector, fill it and then have the object have a constructor that takes a vector.  If the object is going to list each item as a separate variable instead of being a vector then a constructor is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at `std::vector`?

A *row* is a container of *columns*.  The container to use is `std::vector`.

We'll use two structs:  `Data_Headers` and `Data_Rows`:

```
struct Data_Headers
{
    std::vector<std::string> column_headers;
};
struct Data_Rows
{
    std::vector</* data type */> column_data;
};
```

You can access the row's data by:

```
Data_Type column1_data = row.column_data[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is use a `std::map` with `string` keys. For example:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> colNames;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < content[i].size(); j++) {
        std::string column = "col" + std::to_string(j);
        colNames[column] = content[i][j];

    }
}
```

Comment: Note: If the numbering is sequential, an array or array-like container will kick the stuffing out of a `map` in terms of performance and storage consumed.

Comment: Unfortunately, all this is for the opening stages of a "learn a new language on your own" class I have to take. Normally I would just leave it as a vector or perhaps a map if things need to be called randomly later, but the assignment requires the csv data to be stored in objects very specifically.

Comment: Well, I can not think of any teacher that recommend to create hundreds of members for a class parsing a CSV. You might wanna try to ask your teacher about the exercice purpose again.

Comment: Might be the ol' "Write yourself a simple `std::vector` replacement" assignment without the instructor coming right out and saying "Write yourself a simple `std::vector` replacement."